# Are nuclear weapons simply non-existent in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force-awakens

The resistance is attacks the Starkiller Base with what appears to be pretty small time ammunition even by modern earth missiles, which requires a long running sequence of repeated flybys.  The objective, IIRC was to destroy a critical piece of machinery on the surface which would then destabilize the entire planet/weapon (feel free to correct in edit if I remember incorrectly).  OK cool, but then why the force wouldn't they just drop a nuclear bomb on it?  Have nuclear weapons been used any other time in Star Wars (including EU), or, like smart phones, have they just not been invented in that world?

Comment: Since you're allowing EU (i.e. Legends) this is a dupe of [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/27419/31936). If you restrict to canon, this wouldn't be a dupe.

Comment: @Null fair enough!

Comment: So, are you going to restrict to canon or should we close as a dupe?

Comment: It's not Star Wars style. Nuclear weapons would have made pretty short work of the Rebel base on Hoth or the Imperial bunker on Endor, too, but this isn't *Aliens*. ("I say we take off, and nuke the site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.")

Comment: close as dupe is ok

Answer (score 6):

Actually, they **did** use nuclear weapons.

X-Wings are armed with proton torpedoes, which according to (at least, EU/Legends canon) are nuclear.